# highchart csv export in gauge option gives first calumn with value 0

Tags: csv, highcharts, gauge

```
var gaugeOptions = {
        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge'
        },
        title: null,
        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '85%'],
            size: '140%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: {
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#FADCB5',
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },
        exporting: {
            csv:{
                columnHeaderFormatter:function(item, key, series){
                    if(key === 'y'){
                        return 'Total Stock (%)';
                    }else if(key === '' || key === undefined){
                        return 'Micromarket';
                    }
                }
            },
            buttons:{
                contextButton:{
                    menuItems: [{
                        textKey: 'downloadCSV',
                        onclick: function (){
                            this.downloadCSV();
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            stops: [
                [0.1, '#F2A23C'], // orange
                [0.5, '#F2A23C'], 
                [0.9, '#F2A23C'] 
            ],
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorTickInterval: null,
            tickPixelInterval: 400,
            tickWidth: 0,
            title: {
                y: -70
            },
            labels: {
                y: 16
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    y: 5,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true
                },
            }
        }
    };

    // The speed gauge
    $('#container').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Speed',
            data: [18.41],
            includeInCSVExport:false,
            dataLabels: {
                format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{}</span><br/>' +
                       '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver"></span></div>'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
            }
        },{
            name: 'Foo',
            type: 'gauge',
            data: [18.41]
        }]

    }));

    // Bring life to the dials
    setInterval(function () {
        // Speed
        var chart = $('#container-speed').highcharts(),
            point,
            newVal,
            inc;

        if(chart){
            point = chart.series[0].points[0];
            inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
            newVal = point.y + inc;

            if(newVal < 0 || newVal > 100){
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }

            point.update(newVal);
            point = chart.series[1].points[0];
            point.update(newVal);
        }

    }, 2000);
```

Hi

There is issue with my csv export for gauge chart.

when I export a chart as a csv it downloades the chart as first column with value 0.

Is there any way to avoid that and get only one column for gauge type charts.

currently my csv contains data like below after downloading :
e.g. Micromarket | total stock (%)
         0       |     18.41

But i want data should be like this after download :
e.g. total stock (%)
       18.41

Please refer my below JS fiddle link for reference.
https://jsfiddle.net/pc9ggjm4/1/

Comment: I cannot find any option to do this, but you can try to hack this plugin. You can wrap chart.getDataRows method and delete first columns in returning array. See example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pc9ggjm4/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. i already solved by hacking the plug-in code.